# What's the purpose of $wp_did_header?

Tags: templates

It is referenced in load_template but Wp does nothing with it ?!!! so what's the use ?

```
1105  function load_template( $_template_file, $require_once = true ) {
1106      global $posts, $post, $wp_did_header, $wp_did_template_redirect, $wp_query, $wp_rewrite, $wpdb, $wp_version, $wp, $id, $comment, $user_ID;
1107  
1108      if ( is_array( $wp_query->query_vars ) )
1109          extract( $wp_query->query_vars, EXTR_SKIP );
1110  
1111      if ( $require_once )
1112          require_once( $_template_file );
1113      else
1114          require( $_template_file );
1115  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a global variable that can be checked by user functions and filters to see whether or not WordPress has already sent headers.  It's just there to help.